# Button not showing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a quiz application and I ran into a problem. My goal is to make the button show when the check button is clicked but it just won't work.

```js
var pos = 0,
  test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
  ["What is num equal to?", "6", "5", "Potato", "A", "A Variable is something that can store data, like a number or a String (Some text). They can be written as an int or as a string. EXAMPLE: ", "https://s1.postimg.org/nqvwnr0un/Untitled.png"],
  ["What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A"],
  ["What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C"]
];

function _(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion() {


  test = _("test_q");
  text = _("test_t");
  if (pos >= questions.length) {
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;

    return false;
  }

  var BarPercent = (100 / questions.length) * (pos + 1);
  var pb = document.getElementById("pb");
  pb.style.width = BarPercent + "%";
  var qresult = false;

  function showResult(correct) {
    if (correct === true) {
      document.getElementById("Result").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }

  question = questions[pos][0];
  chA = questions[pos][1];
  chB = questions[pos][2];
  chC = questions[pos][3];
  info = questions[pos][5];

  if (questions[pos][6] !== undefined) {
    img = questions[pos][6];
  } else {
    img = ""
  }

  test.innerHTML = "<h4 style='color: #DDD;'>" + info + "</h3><br><img src='" + img + "' style='align: center; width: 50%;'>";
  test.innerHTML += "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "<br><br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button id='sub_button'style='color: green; background-color: #CCC; border: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: left; font-weigth: 100px; font-size: 70px; border-radius: 20px;' onclick='checkAnswer()'>Check</button>";

}

function checkAnswer() {
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }
  if (choice == questions[pos][4]) {
    correct++;
    qresult = true;
    showResult(qresult);

  }
  pos++;
  renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```css
div {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#test_q {
  background-color: #AAA;
  padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: AAA;
  color: #EEE;
}

#pbc {
  width: 100%;
  height: 16px;
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#pbc>#pb {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  background: #1D4;
  width: 0%;
  height: 16px;
  color: #0FF;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#Result {
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#result {
  color: green;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pbc">
  <div id="pb">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="test_q"></div>
<button id="Result" onclick="renderQuestion()">
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
</button>
```

Comment: You have the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: showResult is not defined`. You're calling `showResult` in `checkAnswer` although `showResult` is defined in `renderQuestion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed some of your own code,
Try this:

```js
   

var pos = 0,
       test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
     var questions = [
       ["What is num equal to?", "6", "5", "Potato", "A", "A Variable is something that can store data, like a number or a String (Some text). They can be written as an int or as a string. EXAMPLE: ", "https://s1.postimg.org/nqvwnr0un/Untitled.png"],
       ["What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A"],
       ["What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C"]
     ];

     function _(x) {
       return document.getElementById(x);
     }

     function renderQuestion() {


       test = _("test_q");
       text = _("test_t");
       if (pos >= questions.length) {
         test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
         pos = 0;
         correct = 0;

         return false;
       }

       var BarPercent = (100 / questions.length) * (pos + 1);
       var pb = document.getElementById("pb");
       pb.style.width = BarPercent + "%";
       var qresult = false;



       question = questions[pos][0];
       chA = questions[pos][1];
       chB = questions[pos][2];
       chC = questions[pos][3];
       info = questions[pos][5];

       if (questions[pos][6] !== undefined) {
         img = questions[pos][6];
       } else {
         img = ""
       }

       test.innerHTML = "<h4 style='color: #DDD;'>" + info + "</h3><br><img src='" + img + "' style='align: center; width: 50%;'>";
       test.innerHTML += "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
       test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "<br>";
       test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "<br>";
       test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "<br><br>";
       test.innerHTML += "<button id='sub_button'style='color: green; background-color: #CCC; border: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: left; font-weigth: 100px; font-size: 70px; border-radius: 20px;' onclick='checkAnswer()'>Check</button>";

     }
     function showResult(correct) {
         if (correct === true) {
           document.getElementById("Result").style.display = "block";
         }
     }
     function checkAnswer() {
       choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
       for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
         if (choices[i].checked) {
           choice = choices[i].value;
         }
       }
       if (choice == questions[pos][4]) {
         correct++;
         qresult = true;
         showResult(qresult);

       }
       pos++;
       renderQuestion();
     }
     window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```css
    div {
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    #test_q {
      background-color: #AAA;
      padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
    }

    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-color: AAA;
      color: #EEE;
    }

    #pbc {
      width: 100%;
      height: 16px;
      background: #444;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #pbc>#pb {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      background: #1D4;
      width: 0%;
      height: 16px;
      color: #0FF;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    #Result {
      margin-top: 150px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: 0px;
      display: none;
    }

    #result {
      color: green;
      text-align: left;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="pbc">
  <div id="pb">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="test_q"></div>
<button id="Result" onclick="renderQuestion()">
  <h1 id="result"></h1>
</button>
```

Comment: It works! I would have never caught that. I will keep pushinh on in with my application!